# How to create an ERD Model with these elements and which elements gets foreign keys?

Tags: sql, erd

How to create an ERD Model with these elements?

**Entities**

```
Route - Route_ID, Fare

Stop - Stop_ID, Stop_Name

Schedule - Schedule_ID, Departure_Date, Arrival_Date

Train - Train_ID, Train_Capacity

Driver - Driver_ID, Driver_Name
```

**Relationships**

- A Train can be associated with one or many train drivers.
- A Driver can driver one train.
- A schedule is handled by a train.
- A Train can have multiple schedules.
- A Route has multiple train schedules.
- A Route has many stops.
- A Stop can belong to many routes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework I am just explain how to get started doing it

Before you start drawing an entity relationship diagram you need to understand the [Relationship Cardinalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)) between the entities

> A Train can be associated with one or many train Drivers

means there is a one to many mandatory relationship between Train and Driver entities

> A Train can have multiple schedules

means there is a one to many mandatory relationship between Train and Schedule entities

Similarly understand  all the relationship Cardinalities

I prefer to use [www.draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) to draw ER diagrams

[image: ER Diagram]

I have drawn an E R Diagram above with the relationships I mentioned draw a smiliar completed diagram for your homework

**Edit**

Yes, You are right ROUTE and STOP have many to many mandatory relationship, a new table needs to be created but it is created in the relational data model but not in the ER diagram. so entities remain same but new table needs to be added in the relational model. Check this [link](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch9.xht) for converting ER diagram to relational model.

Comment: Would ROUTE and STOP have many to many relationship? If that's the case wouldn't a new table/model would be created to show this many to many relationship?